# Jquery id into a javascript array with a freemarker list

Tags: javascript, jquery, freemarker

Im generating some pictures dynamically:

```
<#list content.templates as template>
  <td>
    <img class="event_template" title="${template.getTemplateName()}" id="${template.getTemplateName()}" src="${template.getTemplatePicturePath()}" width="170px" height="140px"/>
  </td>
</#list>
```

In my javascript file, i want to get all of these pictures ids in an array, to use jQuery function etc. on them.

I tried the following:

```
var templates =  [<#list content.templates as temp>$("#"+${temp.getTemplateName()}),</#list>];
```

But i got an error:

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLImageElement]
(jquery-1.8.2.min.js:2)

Do anyone get a clue what's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Help might come quicker if you show the actual rendered markup.

Comment: can you use a class in stead of an array of id's for the selector of your jQuery-function?

Comment: I would like to stick with the ID-s. Maybe my english is the problem, but can i ask you what do you mean with the "actual rendered markup"? I copied the error from the chrome js consol, and it doesnt provide much more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's your problem:
You put the templateName outside the quotes, but it needs to be a string.

Solution:

```
... $("#${temp.getTemplateName()}") ...
```